# How to remove points from Google Streets in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, google-maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm working on a map that has already some points directly from the map.

For example: 'Birdland Golf and Country Club'

Is there any solution to remove it from my map? I only need roads, towns and their names.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't remove any features from a base map layer such as Google maps.

I suggest you to use the `QuickMap Services` plugin instead of `OpenLayers`.
[image]

In the settings of that plugin, you will be able to download the `contributor pack` and have access to a lot of providers.

[image]

You may find one with only labels that you want. I think have a look to `MapSurfer`.